# Prolog - Return false if element of a list is an empty list

Tags: list, prolog

I would like to ensure a list does not contain an empty list, however my attempt does not seem to be working:

```
Predic(X) :- foreach (member (A, X) A \= []).
```

Can anyone offer a correction/better alternative?

Thanks

Comment: It worked, thanks, can you add this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using `foreach/2`: loops for partial lists**

Your solution just needs some minor correction:

```
no_empty_list_inside(L):-
    foreach(member(X,L), X \== []).
```

This works if `L` is a list:

```
?- L = [a,b,c], foreach(member(X,L), X \== []).
L = [a, b, c].
```

but loops if `L` is a partial list:

```
?- L = [z,z|_], foreach(member(X,L), X \== []).
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

and it's not pure and might lead to results like this one due to later unifications:

```
?- L =[E], foreach(member(X,L), X \== []), E=[].
L = [[]],
E = [].
```

**Using just `member/2`: fails for partial lists**

Checking for unification failure between elements and `[]` [instead of testing for non-equivalence] solves the above problems by failing.

```
?- L = [z,z|_], \+ member([], L).
false.

?- L = [X], \+ member([], L).
false.
```

**Using `maplist/2` and `dif/2`: it guarantees `L` will not contain `[]`**

If you want to guarantee that any future instantiation of the partial list `L` will have no `[]` among its elements **and** that any element of `L` that is a free variable won't be unified with `[]`, then use `dif/2` (see [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) for more examples) and `maplist/2`. See this example:

```
?- L=[X], maplist(dif([]), L).
L = [X],
dif(X, []).

?- L = [z,z|_], maplist(dif([]), L).
L = [z, z] ;
L = [z, z, _G1153],
dif(_G1153, []) ;
L = [z, z, _G1197, _G1200],
dif(_G1197, []),
dif(_G1200, []) ;
L = [z, z, _G1241, _G1244, _G1247],
dif(_G1241, []),
dif(_G1244, []),
dif(_G1247, []) .
```

Answer (score 2):

You want that a list does not contain an empty list.  This highly suggests that you want a non-empty list otherwise.

```
without_empty_list1([]).
without_empty_list1([E|Es]) :-
   E = [_|_],   % or more costly dif([], E)
   without_empty_list1(Es).

without_empty_list2(Es) :-
   maplist(dif([]), Es).

without_empty_list3(Es) :-
   maplist(\[_|_]^true, Es).
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can roll your own:

```
list_does_not_contain_empty_list( []     ).
list_does_not_contain_empty_list( [X|Xs] ) :-
  X \= [] ,
  list_does_not_contain_empty_list(Xs)
  .
```

Another alternative might be to use use `member/3`:

```
list_does_not_contain_empty_list(Xs) :- \+ member([],Xs) .
```

You could use `append/3`, but in this context, it doesn't offer any improvements over `member/2`:

```
list_does_not_contain_empty_list(Xs) :- \+ append(_,[[]|_],Xs) .
```

And you could even use `findall/3` (but again, you might as well just use `member/2`):

```
list_does_not_contain_empty_list(Xs) :- findall(X,(member(X,Xs),X=[]),[]) .
```

Comment: @TudorBerariu: not enough coffee this AM.